# Can I set a data breakpoint in runtime in System C (or in Plain Vanilla C++)?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

I have a class in system-C with some data members as such:

```
long double x[8];
```

I'm initializing it in the construction like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    x[i] = 0;
}
```

But the first time I use it in my code I have garbage there.

Because of the way the system is built I can't connect a debugger easily.  Are there any methods to set a data breakpoint in the code so that it tells me where in the code the variables were actually changed, but without hooking up a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try starting a second thread which spins, looking for changes in the variable:

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *ThreadProc(void *arg)
{
  volatile long double *x = (volatile long double *)arg;
  while(1)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      if(x[i] != 0)
      {
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("int 3");  // breakpoint (x86)
      }
  }

  return 0;  // Never reached, but placate the compiler
}
...
pthread_t threadID;
pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, ThreadProc, &x[0]);
```

This will raise a SIGTRAP signal to your application whenever any of the x values is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [printk/syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syslog).

It's old-fashioned, but super duper easy.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Conditional breakpoints](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/06/17/did-you-know-you-can-set-conditional-breakpoints-239.aspx)? You could try for various conditions like first element value is zero or non zero, etc??